# Парсиг подгруппы у Exсel Python

Tags: python, pandas, excel

делаю иерархию на основание excel файла по косвенным признакам
Подскажите есть в Python библиотека которая за меня это сделает, и какие методы использовать ? Как получить  иерархию , которую я раскрываю слева + или - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Ну сам себе отвечу

```py
import zipfile 
import xml.etree.ElementTree
```

И получаю уровни